# Операция побитового сдвига (java)

Tags: java

Недавно начала проходить тему побитового сдвига. Приступила к выполнению задачи и столкнулась с недопониманием кода,который был представлен в литературе:

```
public class ShowBits {
    int numbits; 
    ShowBits(int in) {
        numbits = in;
    }

    void Show(long val) {
        long mask = 1;
        mask <<= numbits - 1;
        int spacer = 0;
        for (; mask != 0; mask >>>= 1) {
            if ((val & mask) != 0) System.out.println("1 ");
            else System.out.println("0 ");
            spacer++;
            if (spacer % 8 == 0) {
                System.out.println("");
                spacer = 0;
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
class ShowBitsDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ShowBits a = new ShowBits(8);

        System.out.println("Число в двоичной системе ");
        a.Show(123);

    }
}
```

Не понимаю следующие строки:
long mask = 1;
mask <<= numbits - 1;
И условие цикла for :(
Если есть возможность порекомендовать мне какую-либо литературу для изучения этого вопроса,то буду очень благодарна!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Тут просто

```
    long mask = 1; // 64 бита 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000001
    mask <<= numbits - 1; // тоже самое что и mask = mask << numbits - 1;
    // сдвиг влево на (numbits - 1) бит т.е. если numbits = 5 то результат будет 
    // mask = mask << 5 - 1
    // mask = 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00010000
    // на деле умножение mask * pow(2,4) или 1*16
```

Второй вопрос

```
    for (; mask != 0; mask >>>= 1)

    // условие mask != 0 - продолжать пока mask не обнулится
    // выражение mask >>>= 1  тоже самое mask = mask >>> 1 или без знаковый сдвиг в 
    // право на деле деление на 2 или mask = mask >>> 1 это mask/2
```

По литературе пройдите по ссылке [тут](https://javarush.ru/groups/posts/1925-pobitovihe-operacii)

PS. Обратите внимание что побитовые операции являются целочисленными